# In Bash shell, what's the difference between "\U" and "\u" for getting Unicode?

Tags: bash, unicode, encoding, echo

It seems that "\u" can only decode four hex digits

root@bemoan[15:36:29]:~# echo -e '\U30'

0

root@bemoan[15:47:01]:~# echo -e '\u30'

0

root@bemoan[15:47:06]:~# echo -e '\u23f0'

⏰

root@bemoan[15:48:40]:~# echo -e '\u1f340'

ἴ0

root@bemoan[15:49:06]:~# echo -e '\U1f340'

U+1f340 "\u1f340" doesn't work, but "\U1f340" works

Comment: Unicode uses U-0000, U+F0123 and U+10FEFE notation. The `\u` and the `\U` may be language dependent. So it depends on the language you are using. Warning Often \U may requires 8 characters. Sometime you can use delimiters e.g. `\u{10FFFF}` In any case, which language are you using (or better, which shell?)

Comment: You may need to test. U+0066 is the letter `f`, so f+the letter a: `echo -e '\U00000066a'` this gives you the expected `fa`, but if you remove a 0, the `a` is interpreted as part of unicode code point and not as string. [My examples are in `zsh`, other shell may have other results]

Comment: I'm using bash, `echo -e '\u00000066a'` doesn't work, I test with javascript, fount out `\U` syntax is invalid, you are right `\u` and `\u` are language dependent, I think when in bash `\U` is a better choice.

Comment: bash: `echo -e '\u0066a'` this works. It is just that \u fill consume 4 characters [so 16 bits] (so only unicode in Basic Multilingual Plan), and \U requires 8 characters [32bits], so you can have emoji (and old characters) [note shell may be smart and if they find a character diffeernt from 0-9A-Fa-f, they may just automatically add 0 at beginning of the number

Answer (score 1):

and welcome to StackOverflow! You are playing with the **bash** shell, and with Unicode text. Those are are both rich and interesting tools. I hope you have fun exploring them.

You are using the command `echo -e`. Take a look at the [entry for `echo` in section 4.2 **Bash Builtin Commands** of the *Bash Reference Manual*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins). It says that "If the -e option is given, interpretation of the following backslash-escaped characters is enabled." Among those characters are:

> `\uHHHH`
>
> the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal value *HHHH* (one to four hex digits)
>
> `\UHHHHHHHH`
>
> the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal value *HHHHHHHH* (one to eight hex digits)

This is exactly what you are seeing.

When you execute `echo -e '\u1f340'`, the `\u` (lowercase 'u') tells **echo** to read the following four, not five, hexadecimal characters to get the Unicode character value. **echo** reads them and prints **U+1F34 GREEK SMALL LETTER IOTA WITH PSILI AND OXIA**. Then **echo** reads the remaining character in the string, `0`, and prints it. This gives what you see: `ἴ0` .

When you execute `echo -e '\U1f340'`, the `\U` (uppercase 'U') tells **echo** to read the following five hexadecimal characters to get the Unicode character value. It would accept one to 8 hexadecimal characters. **echo** reads them and prints **U+1F340 FOUR LEAF CLOVER**. This gives what you see:  .

To find out more about **bash**, I encourage reading the [*Bash Reference Manual*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) from top to bottom. Let most of it go over your head at first. Keep a bookmark to it, and go back to specific sections when you run into problems understanding **bash**. After 40 years with shells like **bash**, I still do this about 2-3 times a month. To find out more about Unicode, I encourage you to start reading through https://home.unicode.org/, starting with an introductory video on the front page. And please come back and ask more good questions at StackOverlow. Then answer a few questions yourself!